# What is a statistical journal with quick turnaround?

Tags: open-source

What are good statistical journals with quick turnaround (fast review cycle), suitable for short notes in mathematical statistics and preferably with open access. An example is Statistics & Probability Letters, however, that journal only has sponsored open access.

Comment: Define fast. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [Statistics Surveys](http://www.i-journals.org/ss/) (but I think they are seeking review more than short note), [Statistica Sinica](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/), or the [Electronic Journal of Statistics](http://www.imstat.org/ejs/). They are not as quoted as SPL, but I hope this may help.